# In windows how to create a shortcut to make a system to shutdown or sleep?

Tags: windows, cmd

how to make a shortcut icon to make our pc to sleep or shutdown.
[this is the desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGYpf.jpg)

Comment: Why do you not use the Sleep key on keyboard (key with a half moon)? There can be configured in the power options of Windows what happens on pressing this key (do nothing, sleep, hibernate). Please note that with Windows shell having the input focus (= Windows Desktop, Windows Taskbar) and pressing Alt+F4 (standard hotkey to exit an application), the dialog window to shutdown opens where you can select which shutdown option to use. The default shutdown option can be also configured in the power options.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new txt file with content:

```
shutdown /s
```

and change the file extension to .bat. Place it on the desktop and double-click to shutdown.

Comment: for sleep what is the command

Comment: my bad its shutdown /h

Comment: @Biboune12. Your answer has a gray displayed __Edit__ link at the bottom in footer. There is no need for a batch file. The __Target__ property of the shortcut file (`.lnk` file) can be configured with `%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /H` to result in the same action without using the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` and a batch file.

Comment: @Biboune12 The option `/h` is for hibernate and the option `/s` for shutdown as it can be read after running in a command prompt window `shutdown /?`. So none of these two options can be used for sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Do the below steps:

1. Right-click in any blank area of your desktop
2. Choose New > Shortcut
3. Copy/paste the command `RUNDLL ….. 0,1,0`
4. Click Next
5. For the name of the shortcut, enter “Put to Sleep Immediately”
6. Click Finish

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a shortcut and in the "target" location, you can type in this

```
cmd /k shutdown -f -p
```

I'm not sure about the rundll one, it might be malicious to be honest

Comment: There is no need to use `cmd /k`. `explorer.exe` uses the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the options as specified in the shortcut file to start `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with the __Target__ posted by you. `cmd.exe` searches for the file `shutdown`, finds hopedfully `%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe` and uses next also the function `CreateProcess` to run this executable. So the round about route via `cmd.exe` is not needed at all.

Comment: I suggest to open a command prompt window and run `shutdown /?` to get displayed the usage help. The options should be specified with `/` (Windows style) and not with `-` (Unix style) although __SHUTDOWN__ supports both. And the options `/f` and `/p` are not really the right options as Ponnusamy V asked for a shortcut to shutdown or sleep and not to force a turn off (power off) of the computer.